# Как создать DataFrame с N столбцами из 1D массива (если длина 1D массива не кратна N - заполнить недостающие элементы нулями)

Tags: python, pandas

У меня есть колонка 'ID', значениями которой нужно заполнить 10 других колонок. Заполнение производить построчно. Если останутся пустые ячейки - заполнить их нолями.

Максимально использовать pandas

ID = [3, 2, 2, 10, 2, 1, 7, 5, 8, 9, 3, 1...]

Вот, что я должна получить:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
def prepare_train_set(path_to_csv_files, session_length=10):
   df = pd.read_csv(path_to_csv_files)
   df['ID'] = pd.factorize(df.site)[0]
   df['frequency'] = df.groupby('ID', as_index=False)['site'].transform(lambda s: s.count())
   dictionary = df[['site', 'ID', 'frequency']].loc[pd.unique(df['ID'])]
   dct = dictionary.set_index('site').T.to_dict('list')
   df2 = pd.DataFrame(columns=['site1','site2' ,'site3 ','site4 ', 'site5','site6',\
                            'site7 ', 'site8', 'site9', 'site10' , 'user_id'])


   print(df) 
   print("======")
   print(dct)
   print("======")


   return dct



import glob
for path in glob.glob(os.path.join(PATH_TO_DATA,'3users/user*[0-9].csv')):
   #print(os.path.isfile(path)) 
   prepare_train_set(path, 10)
```

Comment: Приведите пожалуйста пример входного DF (в виде текста/CSV или в виде Python кода) и того что вы хотите получить на выходе.

Comment: @MaxU  https://drive.google.com/open?id=1EcmlTDqZXyqzulTVVAyWo7v2qm6IzEu8   Изначально нужно написать функцию, которая возвращает словарь и новый датафрейм. вот задание: https://github.com/Yorko/mlcourse_open/blob/master/jupyter_notebooks/project_alice/week1_prepare_dataset.ipynb

Comment: и как должен выглядеть результат? Лучше всего привести небольшой искусственный пример (3-5 строк) входных данных и то, что вы хотите получить на выходе. [Прочтите как правильно задавать вопросы по Pandas...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Comment: Откуда берутся значения для “user_id”?

Comment: @MaxU Так как я обрабатываю много датафреймов, каждый из которых отвечает за отдельного пользователя, то соответственно user_id  - порядковый номер пользователя

Comment: Т.е. У вас уже есть DF который содержит столбец «user_id” и к нему надо добавить столбцы “site1”, ..., “site10”?

Comment: @MaxU у меня  нет столбца user_id. его тоже нужно заполнить. при помощи цикла for я передаю датафреймы в функцию prepare_train_set.  в название csv-файла входит id пользователя. как мне считать номер юзера? названия csv-файлов выглядят так: "user0006.csv", "user0013", "user0046".

Comment: @MaxU да, значения ID у меня уже есть. нужно только заполнить столбцы "site*"этими  значениями

Answer (score 1):

Пример:

```
In [73]: ID = np.random.randint(100, size=(24))

In [74]: ID
Out[74]: array([37, 33,  3,  7,  9, 30, 60, 20, 55, 97, 94,  4,  3, 87, 28, 22, 62, 28, 97, 70,  3, 57, 21, 18])

In [75]: %paste
user_id = 1
N = 10          # число столбцов
data = np.pad(ID, (0, int(np.ceil(len(ID) / N)) * N - len(ID)), mode='constant')
df = pd.DataFrame(data.reshape(-1, N), columns=np.arange(1, N+1)) \
       .add_prefix('site') \
       .assign(user_id=user_id)

## -- End pasted text --

In [76]: df
Out[76]:
   site1  site2  site3  site4  site5  site6  site7  site8  site9  site10  user_id
0     37     33      3      7      9     30     60     20     55      97        1
1     94      4      3     87     28     22     62     28     97      70        1
2      3     57     21     18      0      0      0      0      0       0        1
```